# Alter database name error

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, alter

I have the following script that I am trying to run through a winforms program that just executes all the scripts in a directory:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC('ALTER DATABASE [AT100Reporting] MODIFY Name = [IngeniumDynamics];')
GO
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following error:

`ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.`

I googled this and the main thing I could find about it was that alter db statements should run in autocommit mode.  A further search made me change my script to

```
USE [master]
GO

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF

EXEC('ALTER DATABASE [AT100Reporting] MODIFY Name = [IngeniumDynamics];')
GO

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
```

Yet I still have the same error.  Does anyone know what I need to do to make this script run properly

I have also tried this without the `EXEC`

Comment: Sounds like one of the other scripts may have started a transaction that's not rolled back or committed.

Comment: This is the first script that gets run

Comment: Then does your program start a transaction before running the scripts?

Comment: It could do actually - I just checked the code that runs the scripts and it looks as if it is creating a transaction to run it in

Comment: That'd be your problem then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joachim Isaksson has pointed out, the problem was not with the script but with the winforms program that was running the scripts - I had my TransactionScope options set to `TransactionScopeOption.Required` but if I changed this to `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress` the query worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use,
**sp_renamedb OldDbName,NewDbName**  to rename the database :

```
exec ('sp_renamedb questionoverflow, stackoverflow')
```

Dynamic Way :

```
declare @OldName varchar(50)='questionoverflow'
declare @NewName varchar(50)='stackoverflow'

exec('sp_renamedb '+@OldName+','+@NewName)
```

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately now I get this error:  The procedure 'sys.sp_renamedb' cannot be executed within a transaction.

Comment: So, You are on the Same database you are renaming and have an transaction specified?

Comment: @N.pSubedi No, the script in the question would put him in `[master]` while renaming `[AT100Reporting]`.

Answer (score 0):

Then It should work :

First Set an Single User Mode : and Rename it.

```
declare @OldName varchar(50)='stackoverflow'
declare @NewName varchar(50)='a'

EXEC('ALTER DATABASE '+@OLDNAME + ' SET SINGLE_USER')

exec('sp_renamedb '+@OldName+','+@NewName)

//And again put it in Multi-User Mode ::
EXEC('ALTER DATABASE '+@NewName+ ' SET MULTI_USER')
```